# Can't obtain form data from request lumen

Tags: php, forms, lumen

I have an html form for login in my app. I don't know why I can't obtain the contents of the form in my request within my controller. Here is my form:

```
<div class="loginContainer">
        <form class="signin" method="post" action="/login">
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

The page `/login` redirects to displays this single line:

> {"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password
>   field is required."]}

Here is my `UsersController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Users;

use Log;

class UsersController extends Controller

{

    public function __construct()
    {
 //        $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['authenticate']]);
    }
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {

        Log::info("hiiidsfoiasjdfisa");
        Log::info($request->input('email'));
        Log::info($request->input('password'));
        Log::info(implode("|", $request->all()));
        $this->validate($request, [

            'email' => 'required',

            'password' => 'required'

        ]);

        $user = Users::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

        Log::info($user->password);
        Log::info($user->email);    
        if(Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)){

            $apikey = base64_encode(str_random(40));
            Users::where('email', $request->input('email'))->update(['api_key' => "$apikey"]);;
            return response()->json(['status' => 'success','api_key' => $apikey]);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'fail'],401);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I tried logging the contents of my `$request` variable, but all of them return empty in the log file.

Please help!

Comment: You don't use name attributes in your form for your inputs.

Comment: @VincentDecaux I just realized that. My form is working now. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use name attributes for your inputs :

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
```